# Prove Fredholm's theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

I'm trying to show the Fredholm alternative, is one of **Fredholm's theorems**.

> Let $T$ is a compact operator and $T:E \to E$. where $E$ is a Banach space.
>
> We consider the equation:
> $$u-Tu=f \tag 1$$
>
> Prove that exactly one of the following must hold:
>
> - 1/ *Either* $\forall f$ then the equation $(1)$ has a **unique solution** iff $f \in \left[ \ker(I-T^*)\right ]^\perp $;
> - 2/ *Or* the equation $u-Tu=0$ has $n$ **linearly independent solutions**.

====================================

I have thought about it but I still have no solution.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Try first the proof when $E$ is finite dimensional $T$ is just a matrix. Can you show if $(I-T)u=f$ has two solutions then the homogeneous system $(I-T)u=0$ has many solutions? By the way, in point number $2$, what is $n$? It cannot be the dimension of the space since for $E$ finite dimensional this is not true. $n$ would be the dimension of the Kernel of $I-T$. So $2$ must say that that $n>0$.

Comment: Then use a pairing with the elements of the dual. $<(I-T)u,v>=<u,(I-T^*)v>$, for $u$ in the dual space. Use that $<u,v>=0$ for all $v$, implies $u=0$.

Comment: Dear @kimtahe6, my intention with this comment is not to be unpolite, but rather to show you that there are others source than this site.  A simple google search gives me plenty of proofs for this theorem. Also it is also contained in any good book of functional analysis, for example, Brezis book Theorem 6.6. which can be found in the next link:

Comment: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDkQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbbs.sciencenet.cn%2Fupload%2Fblog%2Ffile%2F2010%2F12%2F2010127131928961750.pdf&ei=2nB6UtL7FKWhsAT_6YCIAg&usg=AFQjCNGEZbxtZ-a_IyE9kq11fdflkeqvEg&sig2=ofi_TX0tJKxVjGOeSVTJIA

Comment: @ABC, the statement of 2 is right.

Comment: Yes, thanks **ABC** and **Tomás**. It's very useful to me.

Comment: Let me see... $T:=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$. Then $I-T=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$. With a $1$ dimensional kernel. So $n$ cannot be the dimension $2$ of $E$.